# In AWS Glacier, is there any way to reduce request of file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

When I upload an archive, I know that uploading price is null, but requests gone in more than 200 000, so my estimated bill is something 15-20 $, so I get one way, I put it my all files to a zip or tar (Compress), & is there any alternate way to reduce my requests to upload archive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, glacier is built for archives, i.e for retaining data on a very long term, where retrievals are infrequent and unusual. It should not be accessed unless very rare occasion. Think about Glacier as a warehouse where you would pack up your data and consign them.

So you should not do a lot of requests to Glacier, and if so you should consider using S3 instead.

That been said, you should avoid to zip/tar all your files in one archive file, as you can retrieve up to 5% of your average monthly storage for free each month.

However, keep in mind that each archive object has 32 kb of data overhead associated with it. Thus, an archive size of 3.2 MB would have only 1% of cost overhead, when a 1KB archive would have 97% of cost overhead.

So if you have too small files, aggregate them in larger files; if you have too large files, split them in smaller ones. 
you just have to find the good balance to keep your archives easy enough to browse, e.g using archive descriptions or a local index (e.g nosql store), or both.

Comment: +1 and worth mentioning is that S3 lifecycle policies can transition objects down to Standard/Infrequent-Access and to Glacier after some defined period of time, and S3 objects migrated into Glacier are much easier to manipulate at the file level than anything you store in Glacier yourself... though neither is good for little files.  Excellent point on 97% overhead for a 1KB object, though it might also be said that the overhead is an additive 3200% cost, at that scale. :)